# Why changes on a class affects on other class?

Tags: php, oop

Here is my code: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/0KmJ4)

```
class myclass1 {
    public $myvariable;
}

$obj1 = new myclass1;
$obj2 = $obj1;

$obj1->myvariable = 'something';
echo $obj2->myvariable; //=> something
```

As you see, I've initialized `something` to the first object, but **surprisingly** it will be also applied on the second object. Why really? Actually I need to have two different value in `$myvariable` for both classes, not the same value.

How can I do that?

Comment: _why changes on a class..._ Those are objects and not classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how OOP works. Actually all you need to know is about **pass-by-reference**. Take a look at this:

[image]

In your code, both `$obj1` and `$obj2` are using same memory point. So any change on `$obj1` will be seen also on the `$obj2`. To separate them from each other you need to use [`clone`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php):

```
$obj2 = clone $obj1;
```

By cloning an object you are actually making a copy of it. So the new object won't refer to the old one.

Comment: That's a nice explanation with that gif.